# Does the New Relic REST API support uptime?

Tags: rest, newrelic

I have seen some posts that say that New Relic's REST API does not support uptime information in the past. Is this still the case?

Comment: New Relic does not support uptime, but it does support Apdex which is a good measure of site health.